# Python does not write newline to file, while it is supposed to

Tags: python, newline

```
xadd = open('x.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
hha = [ 'j', 'a', 's', 'o', 'n', '\\n', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n']
a = ''.join(hha)
xadd.write(a)
xadd.close()
```

File's output is *jason\nbrown*. I can assume that the problem is with *a* variable because when I do it normally, without *join* file has newlines. Can someone explain me why is that not working and give me the solution for this problem?

Comment: `\n` is escaped in your list to `\\n`

Comment: yes, but *a = jason\nbrown* and when I just pass it to write, everything works fine

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Ignesus You have to either manually change it to `\n` in your list or just do `"".join(hha).replace("\\n", "\n")`

Comment: _`a = jason\nbrown`_ is not valid in Python.

Comment: xDDDD I know that mate, I did it intentionally without quotes

Comment: @zamir add this comment as an answer, I will give you the best answer. Thank you

Comment: @accdias beh, I wanted to show it's as output, not python value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple fix. Your `\\n` should be `\n`

```
xadd = open('x.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
hha = [ 'j', 'a', 's', 'o', 'n', '\n', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n']
a = ''.join(hha)
xadd.write(a)
xadd.close()
```

Also consider using a context manager when you open files. This will automatically close the file even if an exception occurs and your code doesn't make it to the `.close()` line.

```
with open('x.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as xadd:
    hha = [ 'j', 'a', 's', 'o', 'n', '\n', 'b', 'r', 'o', 'w', 'n']
    a = ''.join(hha)
    xadd.write(a)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, for a project I can not change *\\n* manually, so I did *"".join(hha).replace("\\n", "\n")* thanks to @zamir